# Hide rows in a table from a user group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a table and multiple users access that table. However we would like to hide records in that table from a user group lets say GroupA. So that they don't see any records in their database except the ones that were created by them.

GroupA users should also have an option to add new records and edit their own record.

However, all other users (except groupA) should be able to see all records in the table.

We have SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **row level security**.

One common way is to allow access to the table only via a view. 
(You can also write into a view).

The view must contain a WHERE statement which selects the rows the user is allowed to see.

BTW, be sure to use `ORIGINAL_LOGIN` when you reference to the current user.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a view on the table for GroupA restricting records with appropriate criteria and grant SELECT to GroupA on view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we also need to give them permissions to add new records. Can they do it via view?

Comment: Yes, if you select * from table where user = groupA they will be able to update and add records